# Evaluating string differences

Tags: python

I have a problem for class where I need to compare strings ie. 'truck' vs 'trunk' and return the FIRST position in which the strings differ. I have managed to solve the initial part but I run into trouble when I encounter strings of different lengths ie. 'truck' vs 'trucks'. I've tried a few different methods before deleting and going back to square 1 so I'm hoping to get some advice here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My current code is below.

```
IDENTICAL = -1

def singleline_diff(line1, line2):
    
    short = min(len(line1),len(line2))
    
    for i in range(0,short):
        
        if line1[i] == line2[i]:
            continue

        else:
            return i
  
    else:
        return IDENTICAL


word1 = 'truck'
word2 = 'trunk'
prob1 = singleline_diff(word1, word2)

print(prob1)
```

Comment: 1) You have calculated the lengths, so move them to their own variables and compare. 2) What are you supposed to return when they are different lengths?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "position in which the strings differ" Does that mean the strings can only differ in 1 position? Or can they be completely different? What would be the expected out of  singleline_diff("StackOverflow", "overflowstack")

Comment: I added to my post specifying that the code is expected to find the FIRST difference in the strings. In your example the result would be 0 due to "S" being different from "o". Sorry for not being more specific.

Comment: @Nick ok perfect, then check my answer should work for you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use zip + enumerate.

zip combines 2 iterables like lists or strings. If you loop through it you get pairs of one character of word1 in a tupel with the character on the same position in word2.

enumerate returns the index of the current loop.
since return stops all activities you can use that to return the index (from enumerate) once the tupel `w` (which comes from `zip()` has a different character on position 0 and 1

```
def singleline_diff(word1, word2):
    
    word1 = word1.ljust(len(word2))
    word2 = word2.ljust(len(word1))
    
    for i,w in enumerate(zip(word1, word2)):
        if w[0] != w[1]:
            return i
        
    return "Identical"
    
word1 = 'truck'
word2 = 'trucks' 
print(singleline_diff(word1, word2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this still doesn't solve the problem I have with 'truck' vs 'trucks' in which the returned value should be the index loc of 's'.

Comment: why? what is the problem? The function returns 3 which is the the 4th character of the strings.

Comment: Try word1 = 'truck' and word2 = 'trucks'

Comment: @Nick try this then, just artificially lengthen the smaller word until it has the same length as the longer one.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks! I was unfamiliar with ljust.

Comment: Glad I could help! Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return IDENTICAL if `line1==line2` evaluates to true. If there lengths are uneven and no differences are found, just return `short`.

```
def singleline_diff(line1, line2):
    if line1 == line2:
         return IDENTICAL
    short = min(len(line1),len(line2))
    for i in range(0,short):
        if line1[i] == line2[i]:
            continue
        else:
            return i
    return short
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, providing details as to how to reached the conclusion and your thought process will surely help the fellow asker. See [How to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: How does returning the length of the strings help?

Comment: It is the first index unequal in both strings, according to the requirements of the question

Comment: you should return `short + 1` because if both are equal upto the part of same length, the last index pos. +1 will be different

Comment: For a string of length 5, the first index out of range is actually 5 itself